# Tell the add-in to open Visual Studio and jump to debug mode on a certain line of code?

Tags: vsto

I have created a COM add-in for Excel.

I know that I can enter debug points into my code and then choose to "play" my code from Visual Studio. When a debug point is hit, execution stops and I enter debug mode.

But is it possible to create debug points that cause execution to stop and debug mode to start when I am not running my code via "play" in visual studio but just opening an Excel file as normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the debugger after you run Excel manually outside of Visual Studio. See [Attach to Running Processes with the Visual Studio Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx) and [How to: Attach to a Running Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/c6wf8e4z(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information.